# How can I Change type Of Django Calendar With Persian Calendar?

Tags: python, django, persian-calendar

I use `Django 1.6`.

When I have a field that have `DateTimeField` type, `Django` automatically use `Django calendar`.

But in `Iran` we use `Persian Calendar` (or `Jalali Calendar` or `Farsi Calendar`).

How can I change Django auto generation because it generate `Persian calendar` in page?

In other hand, I want change `default calendar` with `Persian Calendar`?

[image]

Comment: How did u manage it? I wanna do the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will likely have to implement your own [custom widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) - I do not think Django provides a Persian calendar widget at this point in time.

There is an available [code snippet for a Persian DateTime widget](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2612/) that I was able to locate, but have not yet tested.  If it is not a perfect fit, then hopefully it will aid you in writing your own solution.

Answer (score 14):

you can use [django-jalali-date](https://github.com/a-roomana/django-jalali-date). Easy conversion of DateTimeFiled to JalaliDateTimeField within the admin site. only by inheritance a class!

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'jalali_date',
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
from jalali_date import datetime2jalali, date2jalali

def my_view(request):
     jalali_join = datetime2jalali(request.user.date_joined).strftime('%y/%m/%d _ %H:%M:%S')
```

template.html

```
{% load jalali_tags %}

<p>{{ request.user.date_joined|to_jalali:'%y/%m/%d _ %H:%M:%S' }}</p>
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from jalali_date.admin import ModelAdminJalaliMixin, StackedInlineJalaliMixin, TabularInlineJalaliMixin  

class MyInlines1(TabularInlineJalaliMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = SecendModel

class MyInlines2(StackedInlineJalaliMixin, admin.StackedInline):
    model = ThirdModel

@admin.register(FirstModel)
class FirstModelAdmin(ModelAdminJalaliMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MyInlines1, MyInlines2, )
    readonly_fields = ('some_fields', 'date_field',)
```

[image: example of result!]

Comment: please explain how to use this app in model, views and templates

Comment: @Arman could you please explain how to implement  a date field in model via this package. I want to know how to store posted value in database as a date or datetime field.

Comment: it is only a forked project, main project is [django-jallali](https://github.com/slashmili/django-jalali)

Comment: Did you look at the codes of both projects? You judged hastily
I used the jdatetime, no django-jalali @eisanahardani

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the accepted answer, the Jalali `DateField`, with its appropriate date picker can also be implemented without the use of any custom `widget`. 
First you must specify your `DateField` to accept its input in the Jalali format. This can be achieved through [this custom model field](https://github.com/slashmili/django-jalali)
:

```
from django_jalali.db import models as jmodels

class Order(models.Model):
delivery_date =  jmodels.jDateTimeField(verbose_name='تاریخ تحویل')
```

Now, for displaying the date picker to the user, you can use any desired javascript date picker that suits your needs, something like [This Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/mousavian/bootstrap-jalali-datepicker).
Assuming the field is going to be displayed as part of a `model form,` you can specify the `HTML` `id` or `class` of the `widget` responsible for rendering it:

```
class Order(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Order
    widgets = {
        'delivery_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'id':'datepicker'}),
    }
```

Finally in your template, you only need to initialize the date picker:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 2,
            maxDate: "+10D",
            isRTL: true
        });

    });
   </script>
```

Here is how it would look like in the end:
[image: Jalali Date Picker]

Comment: The JDateField seems to use Gregorian DateField's validation. It causes a problem on 31th of second months. Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need Persian DateField (for example for birthday), this tiny code will do it

```
YEAR_CHOICES = range(1377, 1300, -1)
MONTH_CHOICES = {1: 'فروردین',2: 'اردیبهشت',3: 'خرداد',4: 'تیر',5: 'مرداد',6: 'شهریور',7: 'مهر',8: 'آبان',9: 'آذر',10: 'دی',11: 'بهمن',12: 'اسفند'}

class ProfileUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUpdate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['birthday'] = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(empty_label=['سال', 'ماه', 'روز'], years=YEAR_CHOICES, months=MONTH_CHOICES))
```